# Confused about dot product in cross track error calculation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Above is an image from a self driving course I'm taking, in the picture, he said the red line could be calculated using dot product as shown in the red formula on the top right and below. 
[image]

Could someone explain to me how this dot product works? I do not understand why there is a subtraction at all.

Geometrically, P1 is at (x1, y1), P2 is at (x2, y2) and there is another point P at (x, y). R is the line between P and P1. The deltas are calculated from P1 and P2

Comment: It's quite hard to see anything without context. What do all those lines and symbols stand for?

Comment: @David, I've added some comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ is the black vector, and $\Delta$ seems to be the green vector. To compute the distance $CTE$ we can compute the component of $R$ that is *perpendicular* to $\Delta$.

To get the (unnormalized) component of $R$ that is *parallel* to $\Delta$ we can just project it onto a vector parallel to $\Delta$, that is, taking the scalar product. To get the $CTE$ however we need to consider the scalar product of $R$ with a vector that is *perpendicular* to $\Delta$. A vector $\Delta_\perp$ that is perpendicular to $\Delta$ can be computed by rotating $\Delta$ by 90°: So we get

$$\Delta_\perp = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\Delta = (-\Delta_y, \Delta_x)^t$$

(here the matrix is a 90° rotation) and therefore

$$CTE \propto R \cdot \Delta_\perp = -R_x \Delta_y + R_y \Delta_x$$